# Recursively printing out possible words from a phone number

Tags: java, recursion, combinatorics

I am having problems with this programming assignment... (It's homework)
The goal of the program is to look up all the 7 digit phone numbers in an input file and find the possible words that they may make(ex. 1 = a/b/c...), then look them up in the text file to see if they are a proper word. So far my program seems to run okay, and when i put a println statement in my recursive function, i see all the results i expect. The problem however, is that i see a word that is printed, ex "cat", and it does not print it even though it exists in the look up file. Sorry if this is a bad description. I have attached my program code.

Thanks,
P.S. I have looked at the other threads similar to my question but they have not helped.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PhoneWords
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter fstream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(new File("telephones.txt"));
    Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
    String current = "";

    while(numbers.hasNext())
    {
        current = numbers.next().toLowerCase();
        current = current.replaceAll("-", "");

        fstream.println(toWordString("", current, words));
        System.out.println(toWordString("", current, words));

    }

    fstream.close();
    numbers.close();
    words.close();
}




public static String toWordString(String word, String number, Scanner ifstream)
{
    char[] guess = new char[3];

    if(number.length() == 0)
    {
        if(isFound(word, ifstream))
        {
            System.out.println(word);
                return number + word;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        guess = getPossibleLetters(number.charAt(0));
        number = number.substring(1);

        toWordString(word + guess[0], number, ifstream);
        toWordString(word + guess[1], number, ifstream);
        toWordString(word + guess[2], number, ifstream);
    }

    return number + ": None";
}

public static boolean isFound(String word, Scanner ifstream)
{
    String current = "";
    //System.out.println(word);
    while(ifstream.hasNext())
    {
        current = ifstream.next();

        if(current.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public static char[] getPossibleLetters(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '0':
        case '1':
            throw new NumberFormatException("Digit cannot be 0 or 1");
        case '2':
            return new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        case '3':
            return new char[] {'d', 'e', 'f'};
        case '4':
            return new char[] {'g', 'h', 'i'};
        case '5':
            return new char[] {'j', 'k', 'l'};
        case '6':
            return new char[] {'m', 'n', 'o'};
        case '7':
            return new char[] {'p', 'r', 's'};
        case '8':
            return new char[] {'t', 'u', 'v'};
        default:
            return new char[] {'w', 'x', 'y'};
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `return number + ": None";` this line works?

Comment: The invocation to `toWordString` (for a non-empty number) in `main` will always return "...None"? `words.txt` is scanned only once?

Comment: Why would it always return none? Would it not find the word and return it?

Comment: `toWordString` calls itself recursively but "throws away" the return value from the recursive call.

Comment: Okay, im not to great with this recursion stuff, :(. What do you suggest i do?

Comment: Either collect the results (in a "Collection") and return them all. Or move the `println`s you do in `main` into your `if(isFound(...))` branch - but you might still want to collect the information whether anything has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the following issues in your code:

1, the reason you see the found word printed out but doesn't see it in the output file is you didn't handle the return value of your recursive call to `toWordString` function, the return value in the following block returns to upper layer `toWordString` instead of the `main` function:

```
if(isFound(word, ifstream))
{
    System.out.println(word);
    return number + word;
}
```

you should handle the return value of the 3 recursive call to `toWordString` function, or you add an extra argument (like List) for `toWordString` to hold the return results between recursive calls.

2, You should not use the `Scanner ifstream` as an argument of your `toWordString`, your recursive calls to `toWordString` use the same Scanner Object and the first call to `isFound` would iterate all the tokens in the scanner, the futher calls to `isFound` would always return `false`

you'd better read all the words into a collection in your `main` function, and then pass the collection to `toWordString`